# Php Subtract Date Time

Tags: php, date

I'm having problems with subtracting dates in php..

this is my code.

```
$fulldate_hour_start    = "2013-12-01 01:00:00";
$fulldate_hour_end      = "2013-12-02 08:01:00";
$Result= number_format((((strtotime($fulldate_hour_end) - strtotime($fulldate_hour_start)) / 60) / 60  ),2);
echo $Result;
```

The output was `31.02`

which is should be only `31.01`

I don't know what happened or wrong with my codes.. Thanks for the Help..

Answer (score 2):

```
$fulldate_hour_start    = "2013-12-01 01:00:00";
$fulldate_hour_end      = "2013-12-02 08:01:00";

$difference = strtotime( $fulldate_hour_end .' UTC' ) - strtotime( $fulldate_hour_start .' UTC');

$Result = floor( $difference / 3600 ) .':' .gmdate( 'i', $difference );

echo $Result;
```

Result

```
31:01
```

Answer (score 0):

The time period you are calculating is 31.01666 repeating hours, which `number_format()` rounds up to 31.02 hours, so the result is correct, if you wanted hours and fractions of hours.  If you want hours and minutes then you'll need to change the calculation to consider 60 minutes per hour.